# Disable predefined targets (like CoreBuild and CorePublish) if property is set

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a project structure with several dirs.proj and cs/ccproj files.

When developers and certain builds run, I don't want to generate cloud service .cspkg files (takes too long time when we don't need them). What our build infrastructure team have set up is an extra property "BuildCloudPackages"=='true', which I can use to only build the cloud packages when needed.

I want to stop CorePublish and Build unless BuildCloudPackages is set to true for all ccproj's in a dirs.proj.

Is there a way to retrofit conditions to existing targets? Or Conditionally including a ProjectFile in a dirs.proj. Or conditionally redefine targets inside a Choose/When? Or stop build/publish by disabling some of their preconditions? Or remove Build and CorePublish from default targets on the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it using conditional import, where one disabled the tasks I didn't want to run, and one adds what I need only when I ask for it.

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\targets\DisableBuild.targets"
        Condition="'$(BuildCloudPackages)'!='true'" />
<Import Project="..\..\..\targets\CustomTasks.targets"
        Condition="'$(BuildCloudPackages)'=='true'" />
```

Where the disable file is something like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CoreBuild" />
  <Target Name="CorePublish" />
</Project>
```